# Having a crash in Xcode trying to create a video capture app

Tags: ios, xcode, video, avfoundation

I am new to programming and I am trying to create a video capture that is like in snapchat. I am having trouble recording and saving the video. I do not know obj C but I did go through the documentation and did my best converting over to Swift 2.0.

Can anybody please help, and/or advise of some resources to quickly create a video recorder that will allow to record unto 15 seconds.

The error:

[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:]

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreGraphics

class CameraControllerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var videoPreviewView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Create Capture Session
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    if captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh){
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
    }

    //Add input device
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    //Create Input
    do{
       let captureInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        captureSession.addInput(captureInput)
    }catch let error as NSError{
        NSLog(error.debugDescription)

    }

    //PreviewLayer
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.frame = videoPreviewView.bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    videoPreviewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

    //OutPut
    let format = NSDateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
    let currentFileName = "\(format.stringFromDate(NSDate())).mp4"
    let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let videoFileURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentFileName)





    let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

    movieFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(videoFileURL, recordingDelegate: self)


    if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput){
        captureSession.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
    }
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    captureSession.startRunning()
    captureSession.stopRunning()

}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
    NSLog("Recording did start to file: \(NSURL.debugDescription())")

}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    if let error = error{
        NSLog("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
    }else{
        NSLog("File Output: \(outputFileURL.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: See the following to learn how to debug a crash: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: You need to update your question with the complete error message and point out the exact line causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I realized that I have to commit the configuration first and then add the outputs